# OAuthProblemException - description='AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'refresh_token'

Tags: java, microsoft-teams

This is my MS teams authentication provider code:

```
  try {
            if (durationPassed >= integrationToken.getAuth().getExpiresIn() * 1000) {
                TokenRequestBuilder token = OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation(AuthHelper.getAuthority() + AuthConstants.TOKEN_ENDPOINT)
                        .setClientId(AuthHelper.getClientId()).setScope(AuthHelper.getScopes())
                        .setRefreshToken(integrationToken.getAuth().getRefreshToken())
                        .setGrantType(GrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN).setClientSecret(AuthHelper.getClientSecret())
                        .setRedirectURI(authHelper.getRedirectUrl());

                OAuthClientRequest request = token.buildBodyMessage();
                OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse response = oAuthClient.accessToken(request);
                saveNewTokenData(integrationToken, response, startTime);
            }
            return integrationToken.getAuth().getAccessToken();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I am getting this error:

```
OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'refresh_token'.
Trace ID: 89433eff-047a-476c-92d0-fcf61e7fa100
Correlation ID: 87f28fa7-729f-4c92-8457-3b3d1eb2df45
Timestamp: 2021-07-16 06:01:31Z', uri='https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=400, parameters={}}
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:59)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateErrorResponse(OAuthClientValidator.java:63)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validate(OAuthClientValidator.java:48)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.validate(OAuthClientResponse.java:127)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:96)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:101)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:60)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:120)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:111)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:71)
    at com.ps.addons.chats.teams.auth.provider.TeamAuthenticationProvider.getAccessToken(TeamAuthenticationProvider.java:59)
    at com.ps.addons.chats.teams.auth.provider.TeamAuthenticationProvider.authenticateRequest(TeamAuthenticationProvider.java:31)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:395)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:220)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:200)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseCollectionRequest.send(BaseCollectionRequest.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.UserCollectionRequest.get(UserCollectionRequest.java:76)
    at com.ps.addons.chats.teams.graphql.loader.UserBatchLoader.lambda$load$1(UserBatchLoader.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help. Is there some scope I am missing?

Comment: Hey, Have you added [_offline_access_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access) scope? If not, please add and check.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT I did. I checked this [out](https://community.developers.freshworks.com/t/can-not-connect-to-ms-calendars-api-because-refresh-token-not-set/2339/5). Are you sure this can be the only solution and I might not be doing it correctly?

Comment: Hey, Can you please try change _grant_type_ to _authorization_code_. Can you please check [Get a token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token)? Also have a look at [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token)

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Thank you so much for your efforts. I did add the access_token but what I think worked was clearing and regenerating the integration token from our authentication setup which was being used to feed the refresh_token for the ms request.

Comment: So, Is it solved by doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Clearing and regenerating the integration token from our authentication setup which was being used to feed the refresh_token for the ms request worked. - [Aakash Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5924738/aakash-verma)